# Looking for HUST_ASL dataset (a hand gesture dataset)

Tags: data-request, images, real-time

I have a problem to find the HUST-ASL Dataset (it's a hand gesture dataset acquired with Kinect). The creators mentioned it should be at http://mc.eistar.net/UpLoadFiles/File/hust_asl_dataset.zip, but that link doesn't work.

HUST = Huazhong University of Science & Technology

The reference article is : "Depth-Projection-Map-Based Bag of Contour Fragments for Robust Hand Gesture Recognition".

Comment: Did you mail Mr Bin Feng?

Comment: Yes sir before this post, but unfortunately Mr Bin Feng doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

[HUST Dataset (March 2016)](http://www.handcorpus.org/?p=1596) at [HandCorpus.org](http://www.handcorpus.org/), the *open access repository for sharing data, tools and analyses about human and robotic hands*.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer but the dataset that i mensioned was acquised with kinect and the reference article is : "Depth-Projection-Map-Based Bag of Contour Fragments for Robust Hand Gesture Recognition". Thank you for your timeand help